# Visual Studio plug-ins development, first steps

Tags: visual-studio, plugins, vsx

I would like to make a plug-in for visual studio... But I have no idea where to start.
While it was quite easy to find guides for Eclipse plug-in development, I'm having troubles to find a good guide for VS plug-in development.

I guess what I'm trying to ask here, is where do I start?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I suggest to start here: http://www.mztools.com/resources_vsnet_addins.aspx
This is great set of resource for VS add-in developers. Creating VS add-in is quite easy. Some keywords if you want to search for more: VS add-in (plugin is not very used), VS extensibility, VS automation.

Answer (score 11):

The best place to start for pointers to tools, documentation, etc... is the [Visual Studio Extensibility Dev Center on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsx/default.aspx).

What you want to do next really depends on what you're trying to build. If you want just a simple plugin (maybe a menu command that runs some code against [the Visual Studio Automation model: EnvDTE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/esk3eey8.aspx)), you could do an Addin. (There are templates for Addins in-the-box under Other Project Types -> Extensibility in the New Project dialog.)

If you want your extension to be a "first class citizen" (i.e. full API access like the other extensions in the box), you should download the Visual Studio SDK and create a VSPackage.

While Visual Studio remains (even in 2010) a largely COM-based application, there are managed libraries (e.g. Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.*) and interop assemblies for accomplishing many kinds of extensions.

The Editor in Visual Studio 2010 was rebuilt in managed code and [uses MEF as its extensibility model](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd885122(VS.100).aspx). You can also find templates for MEF-based editor extensions in the Visual Studio SDK for 2010.

Answer (score 4):

there's a codeplex project [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/macros/LineCounterAddin.aspx) that shows how to create a VS plug-in, but I found it to be quite involved, and more detailed around the specific implementation, than a generic 'getting started with plug-ins' guide...

anyway - it might be a starting point for you :)

Answer (score 3):

Never developed a single plug-in for Visual Studio, but nevertheless here are my thoughts.

Plugins for VS were historically a nightmare to build: all these COM interfaces sticking out from various odd ends, WEIRD_CONSTANTS_IN_GLOBAL_SCOPE, etc. If I were to develop a VS plugin, I'd target Visual Studio 2010, which is, as they say, is really nicer in this respect.

Moreover, if your plugin has anything to do with C#/VB.NET code, consider writing a plugin for ReSharper.